# How do you find the gradients of weights and biases in neural network during back propagation?

Tags: gradient-descent, backpropagation, gradient

I have been trying to create a neural network from scratch.

I have been trying to calculate the gradients of the weights and biases of the neural network by watching videos and reading papers, but still have been unable to get a good grasp on it.

z is all the weights multiplied by the nodes of the previse layer plus the bias of the node.
a is the sigmoid of z

I believe I having trouble with the w(L-number) calculations in the formula. Because I believe there should be more w(L-number) and does not work otherwise.

I have added some pictures for clarification:
[image: The weight gradient section]

[image: The bias gradient section]

Comment: More Information:
Formulas: 
z(i) = (w(i) * a(i-1) + b(i) 
a(L) = sigmoid(z(L))

equations for the weights (w) (L is layer):

Comment: 1) dCo/dw(L) = dz(L)/dw(L) * da(L)/dz(L) * dCo/da(L)
2) dCo/dw(L-1) = dz(L-1)/dw(L-1) * da(L-1)/dz(L-1) * dz(L)/da(L-1) * da(L)/dz(L) * dCo/da(L)
3) dCo/dw(L-2) = dz(L-2)/dw(L-2) * da(L-2)/dz(L-2) * dz(L-1)/da(L-2) * da(L-1)/dz(L-1) * dz(L)/da(L-1) * da(L)/dz(L) * dCo/da(L)
4) ...

Comment: I believe this means using the formulas: 

1) dCo/dw(L) = a(L-1) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L)) * 2(a(L) - y) 
2) dCo/dw(L-1) = a(L-2) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L-1)) * w(L) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L)) * 2(a(L) - y) 
3) dCo/dw(L-2) = a(L-2) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L-2)) * w(L-1) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L-1)) * w(L) * sigmoid_derivative(z(L)) * 2(a(L) - y)
4) ...

The biases are the same but dz(L - number)/dw(L) is 1

Comment: It did not let me post all of the information, so here is some above. It is basically what the paper says.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include this information. Moreover, this site supports math typesetting via Mathjax — typesetting is more legible than photos of handwritten equations.